# Apache Spark Rdd persist

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

**Once we persist RDD in memory, for how long it will be there in memory? Can we access the same if we come out of spark shell ?**

Comment: Best way is to query it and find out.

Comment: oh!! gr8 answer

Comment: RDD's are stored as deserialized java objects in spark executor JVM's. They continue to exist as long as the JVM's are active and cease to exist (i.e garbage collected) when exit from spark shell.

Comment: gr8 answer for gr8 question

Comment: @ Raghuveer frm whr did u get such an awesome answer yaar lol........everything u can try out yourself then y r u thr in stackoverflow....... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you come out of your shell then your RDD is no longer accessible or in memory for next instance of spark-shell or any other process.